# How to enable backwards compatibility but make sure my library works on a newer version of java

Tags: java, maven, gradle, backwards-compatibility

I am helping a library upgrade to Java 11 and 17, but the library must still work with Java 8. Is there a way to do this so that the compiler/tests will catch any regressions? It seems that toolchains and source/target compatibility can set a minimum, but I also want to verify the maximum? Currently it seems to me that I would need to have my compile/tests run on the higher version in CI before releasing with the older target.

Comment: First use `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>` ... the most important one...What do you mean by the `maximum`?

Comment: Just compile and run your tests with the newest Java version as well - you have tests, right?

Comment: Maximum, as in we KNOW that it works with Java 11, support Java 8, but cannot guarantee Java 17. So the maximum is Java 11 in that scenario.

Comment: @dan1st I was trying to avoid the double CPU for builds - having to run the tests across the max on top of the minimum.

Comment: You can use `--release`/`maven.compiler.release` - but that can miss some stuff. If you want to be sure, you need to run it multiple times.